# Angular4: HttpClient and HttpParams: passing an object as a value in httpParams.set()

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have a problem with more complex key value pair... what if I wanted to set for a value as an object?

I am having this problem:

```
const includeStr = JSON.stringify({include: 'match-timeline-events'});
const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().set('filter', includeStr);
```

when I use it in:

```
this.http.get(environment.apiPath + '/clientMatches/' + id, {params})
```

I get in the headers then set this

```
(urlencoded): filter:%7B%22include%22:%22match-timeline-events%22%7D
```

but for some reason, the : doesn't get encoded and the string should've been

```
(urlencoded): filter:%7B%22include%22%3A%22match-timeline-events%22%7D
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear from the code above how comes that param key-value is delimited with `:` and not `=`. Probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: what do you mean **:** and not **=**? ... I said this comes through in the headers send in the request... the url generated is: `http://localhost:3000/api/...clientMatches/5987633c508eb519385779c8?filter=%7B%22include%22:%22match-timeline-events%22%7D`

Comment: I was confused by another colon here, `filter:%7B%2...`. Do these params cause troubles on server side? I guess they don't encode : and [other listed chars](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L59-L67) because they are safe for url and just waste bandwidth when being encoded.

Comment: it does cause me problems, yeah :/ loopBack does not recognioze it as a valid filter param

Comment: That's quite strange, a colon shouldn't make a difference, this should work as expected, `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent('%7B%22include%22:%22match-timeline-events%22%7D'))`. I noticed that the url you've posted contains invisible space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) . Do you have ideas where they come from? Can it be a real problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a bug that should be reported. Any way, you can address it with `HttpParams` [custom encoder](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#constructor) that can extend a default one, [`HttpUrlEncodingCodec`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpUrlEncodingCodec).

As it can be seen, `HttpUrlEncodingCodec` uses a [custom function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L33) that [doesn't encode a colon on purpose](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L60).